# Как динамично изменять font-size, чтобы одно слово (повернутое на 90 градусов) занимало всю высоту экрана?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Нужно чтобы при изменении высоты экрана, повернутое слово всегда оставалось растянуто относительно его краев, за счет изменения шрифта. Как это можно сделать? Желательно без JS, но думаю тут без него не обойтись.

```css
.bgString {
    font-size: 100vh;
    height: 0;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="bgString">
  HELLO
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

svg {
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 12 75">
  <text transform="rotate(90 0 0)">Some Text</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Идея использовать svg интересная, но я с ним не работал раньше. При изменении текста на, к примеру, "Test", он у меня остается маленьким размером и не растягивается по высоте.

Comment: Я понял, нужно изменять четвертое значение у viewBox. Опытным путем я вывел что самое подходящее значение это (кол-во символов в слове*10)-5

Comment: Но это все-равно не является ответом на мой вопрос. С таким-же успехом можно просто изменять размер шрифта в CSS используя JS. Мне интересно, есть ли более простые и оптимизированные способы добиться растяжения одного вертикального слова по высоте.

Comment: Я понял что забыл упомянуть чтобы способ был универсальным для разных слов, так что ответ в целом то правильный

Comment: Нужно как-то согласовать это 4 значение viewBox с height в CSS